# How to optimize MySQL select query or make it faster

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a select query, that selects over 50k records from MySQL 5.5 database at once, and this amount is expected to grow. The query contains multiple subquery which is taking over 120s to execute.

Initially some of the `sale_items` and `stock` tables didn't have more that the ID keys, so I added some more:

```
SELECT
  `p`.`id` AS `id`,
  `p`.`Name` AS `Name`,
  `p`.`Created` AS `Created`,
  `p`.`Image` AS `Image`,
  `s`.`company` AS `supplier`,
  `s`.`ID` AS `supplier_id`,
  `c`.`name` AS `category`,
  IFNULL((SELECT
    SUM(`stocks`.`Total_Quantity`)
  FROM `stocks`
  WHERE (`stocks`.`Product_ID` = `p`.`id`)), 0) AS `total_qty`,
  IFNULL((SELECT
    SUM(`sale_items`.`quantity`)
  FROM `sale_items`
  WHERE (`sale_items`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`)), 0) AS `total_sold`,
  IFNULL((SELECT
    SUM(`sale_items`.`quantity`)
  FROM `sale_items`
  WHERE ((`sale_items`.`product_id` = `p`.`id`) AND `sale_items`.`Sale_ID` IN (SELECT
    `refunds`.`Sale_ID`
  FROM `refunds`))), 0) AS `total_refund`
  FROM ((`products` `p`
    LEFT JOIN `cats` `c`
      ON ((`c`.`ID` = `p`.`cat_id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `suppliers` `s`
      ON ((`s`.`ID` = `p`.`supplier_id`)))
```

This is the explain result

```
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------
| id | select_type        | table      | type           | possible_keys          | key                    | key_len | ref     | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | ALL            | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL      | 20981 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED            | p          | ALL            | NULL                   | NULL                   | NULL    | NULL      | 20934 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED            | c          | eq_ref         | PRIMARY                | PRIMARY                | 4       | p.cat_id      |     1 |                          |
|  2 | DERIVED            | s          | eq_ref         | PRIMARY                | PRIMARY                | 4       | p.supplier_id |     1 |                          |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sale_items  | ref            | sales_items_product_id | sales_items_product_id | 5       | p.id   |    33 | Using where              |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | refunds    | index_subquery | IDX_refunds_sale_id    | IDX_refunds_sale_id    | 5       | func    |     1 | Using index; Using where |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sale_items  | ref            | sales_items_product_id | sales_items_product_id | 5       | p.id   |    33 | Using where              |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | stocks     | ref            | IDX_stocks_product_id  | IDX_stocks_product_id  | 5       | p.id    |     1 | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+------------+----------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+---------------------------------
```

I am expecting that the query takes less that 3s at most, but I can't seem to figure out the best way to optimize this query.

Comment: What does [EXPLAIN](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) show?

Comment: For query-optimization questions please include the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements in your question.

Comment: @PM77-1 i have added the explain

Comment: @WillemRenzema this means i would have to add the create table of 6 or more tables.

Comment: This is a tricky one to work on in the abstract - ideally, a SQLFiddle or similar would be useful.

Comment: My first guess is that it's the derived tables which are costing you. Can you write your subqueries as regular outer joins ?

Comment: @Smith Yes it does. It will allow us to see the indexes you currently have, along with the column data types, to see if any are too large or are mismatched, along with other things critical to query optimization.

Comment: Are you sure the EXPLAIN output is from the exact same query?  I do not see any derived tables (subqueries in FROM clause) in your query.

Comment: If you have performance issues with subqueries in MySQL 5.5, the best advice is always to upgrade to a later version!

Comment: @oysteing yes the explain is from the same query

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Pls i would appreciate some pointers on outer joins

Comment: Do you need `LEFT JOIN`?  Or would `JOIN` give you the correct results?

Comment: Typo?  `saleitems` vs `sale_items`

Comment: It _may_ help to use a `JOIN` instead of `IN ( SELECT ... )`

Comment: How many rows does the query return?  If it is 21K (as the `EXPLAIN` suggests), then what will the client do with that much data all at once?

Comment: @RickJames Typo fixed, still same with join. The 21k rows if for reportviewer. It is pulling a report of balances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query looks fine to me. You select all data and aggregate some of it. This takes time. Your explain plan shows there are indexes on the IDs, which is good. And at a first glance there is not much we seem to be able to do here...

What you *can* do, though, is provide covering indexes, i.e. indexes that contain all columns you need from a table, so the data can be taken from the index directly.

```
create index idx1 on cats(id, name);
create index idx2 on suppliers(id, company);
create index idx3 on stocks(product_id, total_quantity);
create index idx4 on sale_items(product_id, quantity, sale_id);
```

This can really boost your query.

What you can try About the query itself is to move the subqueries to the `FROM` clause. MySQL's optimizer is not great, so although it should get the same execution plan, it may well be that it favors the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  p.created,
  p.image,
  s.company as supplier,
  s.id AS supplier_id,
  c.name AS category,
  COALESCE(st.total, 0) AS total_qty,
  COALESCE(si.total, 0) AS total_sold,
  COALESCE(si.refund, 0) AS total_refund
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN cats c ON c.id = p.cat_id
LEFT JOIN suppliers s ON s.id = p.supplier_id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(total_quantity) AS total
  FROM stocks 
  GROUP BY product_id
) st ON st.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    SUM(quantity) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sale_id IN (SELECT sale_id FROM refunds) THEN quantity END) as refund
  FROM sale_items
  GROUP BY product_id
) si ON si.product_id = p.id;
```

(If `sale_id` is unique in `refunds`, then you can even join it to `sale_items`. Again: this should usually not make a difference, but in MySQL it may still. MySQL was once notorious for treating `IN` clauses much worse than the `FROM` clause. This may not be the case anymore, I don't know. You can try - if `refunds.sale_id` is unique).

Comment: How fast is the original query after adding the indexes?  After reformulating this way?  (That is, is this a new starting point for the Question?)